# Logical OR in Java shows unexpected results

Tags: java, logical-or

Here's my code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = s.nextInt();
String [] pair_left = new String[t];
String [] pair_right = new String[t];

for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    pair_left[i] = s.next();
    pair_right[i] = s.next();
}
HashSet hs1=new HashSet();
HashSet hs2=new HashSet();
int j=0;
for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
    if(hs1.add(pair_left[i])||hs2.add(pair_right[i])){
      j++;
      System.out.println(j);
    }
    else {      
       System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

and the input is :

```
5
john tom
john mary
john tom
mary anna
mary anna
```

now when `i=2` then `hs1.add(pair_left[i])` returns false and then it goes to `hs2.add(pair_right[i])`which also return 'false'so `hs1.add(pair_left[i])||hs2.add(pair_right[i])` should return 'false' but in my case it shows `true`. Why?

And when I replace logical OR with bitwise OR then it shows correct result.
If there any better approach of doing this then give that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware that `||` logical OR is short circuited, so if `hs1.add(pair_left[i])` returns true, `hs2.add(pair_right[i])` is not evaluated.

On the other hand, as you noticed, when you use `|`, which is non-short circuited logical OR (note that `|` is **not only** bitwise OR), both operands are always evaluated.

Comment: but if hs1.add(pair_left[i]) returns false then it evaluates hs2.add(pair_right[i]) which is also false then hs1.add(pair_left[i])||hs2.add(pair_right[i]) should return false but in my case it returns true why?

Comment: @JatinBansal In the first iteration (i==0), `hs1.add(pair_left[i])` returns true (since the Set was empty), so `hs2.add(pair_right[i])` is not evaluated. Therefore when i==2, `hs1.add(pair_left[i])` returns false but `hs2.add(pair_right[i])` returns true (since tom wasn't added in the first iteration).

Comment: ok thanks i got it